# Blank home page after creating Zend index.phtml

Tags: zend-framework, httpd.conf

I am just starting with Zend and am having an issue wherein browsing http://localhost renders a blank page. I've set httpd.conf documentroot to /var/www/HTML/public and enabled Zend_layout in bootstrap.PHP. My index.phtml is locatrd in the suggested directory per the .ZF manual.

Does IndexComtroller have to specifically call my index.phtml view?  What other things should I check?

Thanks Much!

EDIT:  I checked httpd.conf and noted mod rewrite is enabled.  .htaccess file in /var/www/html/public has ReWrite Engine ON etc.  I've not created a VirtualHost entry in httpd.conf.  I simply defined DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"  Is a virtualhost required to run the framework?

EDIT2:  I used php -f /var/www/html/public/index.php and received the following

```
PHP Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory in /var/www/html/public/index.php on line 18
PHP Fatal Error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' 
(include_path=':.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/public/index.php
on line 18
```

Comment: UPDATE:  A check of the error_log shows the following: Failed opening required 'var/www/html/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is make sure you have the appropriate error reporting enabled for development. Make sure these are set in your `application.ini` file

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Once you've done this, re-test and post back any error messages you receive.

Comment: These are set as specified. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not setup Zend Framework in your include_path - did you copy the Zend-subdirectory of the installation packages *libs*-folder into */usr/share/php*, so that you now have a directory called */usr/share/php/Zend/*?

Comment: The directory /usr/share/php does not exist Should I use /usr/lib/php instead?

Comment: yes, and unzip the libs/Zend/-Directory of the installation package in it.

Comment: I copied the Zend folder to /usr/lib/php and error still persists:(

Comment: So you now have a folder called /usr/lib/php/Zend/ with some files in, especially /usr/lib/php/Zend/Application.php?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's late here - it has to reside in /usr/share/php and not /usr/lib/php. please move the Zend-folder there.